# Code Sign error in xcode

Tags: xcode4.5

When I try to test an app in the most current version of Xcode I get this issue
"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains". what i'm wanting to know is it because i'm using the free version of apple developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop iOS applications with the free version of Xcode, and run them in the emulator.

To run them on an actual device/phone, even your own, you need to pay the $99/year fee to get a developer certificate.

Maybe I should mention there are workarounds by jailbreaking the phone you want to test on, but for that information I'll refer to Google :)